# Dimension properties of mondrian for saiku

Tags: dimension, mondrian, saiku

I am designing a Cube in Mondrian schema for Saiku server.
Following is the Dimension of the demo Foodmart schema which I need to replicate even for the cube I will be creating.
I am not able to understand the role of 'Property' under 'Level'. Also, why this list of 'Properties' does not appear as Dimensions on Saiku.

```
<Dimension name="Store">
    <Hierarchy hasAll="true" primaryKey="store_id">
        <Table name="store"/>
        <Level name="Store Country" column="store_country" uniqueMembers="true"/>
        <Level name="Store State" column="store_state" uniqueMembers="true"/>
        <Level name="Store City" column="store_city" uniqueMembers="false"/>
        <Level name="Store Name" column="store_name" uniqueMembers="true">
            <Property name="Store Type" column="store_type"/>
            <Property name="Store Manager" column="store_manager"/>
            <Property name="Store Sqft" column="store_sqft" type="Numeric"/>
            <Property name="Grocery Sqft" column="grocery_sqft" type="Numeric"/>
            <Property name="Frozen Sqft" column="frozen_sqft" type="Numeric"/>
            <Property name="Meat Sqft" column="meat_sqft" type="Numeric"/>
            <Property name="Has coffee bar" column="coffee_bar" type="Boolean"/>
            <Property name="Street address" column="store_street_address" type="String"/>
        </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
```

Answer (score 1):

Saiku doesn't (yet) support properties.  I believe this was down to a lack of support in olap4j but now analyzer uses olap4j i guess it must be resolved there.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare these properties as levels. In fact, it would be mistake because of hierarchy but in practice OLAP server shows it right because it's possible that one level have only one sub level and only one sub sub level.